# OS X Server 10.6.8 keeps crashing

Tags: macos, apache, perl, server

I have an OS X Server 10.4 that started Kernel Panicking on me late december. It had Mail, Web and SQL services turned on.
I switched to another Mac, problem persisted. Updated to 10.6.8, no difference. Switched to a third Mac, no difference.
In short; It gets 1-3 Kernel Panics per day.

I have noticed that the CPU load slowly rises until it panics.

So during this weekend I turned off all services except Mail. It worked very good during the weekend. Today 1500 (15pm) I turned on Web services, and after that the CPU load started to rise...

Among the processes I found more than 300 perl processes owned by the _www user. As well as the clamavd (owned by amisvd if I remember correctly) eating a lot of memory.

Clamavd is the anti virus and spam processes, right? I have tried to turn them off in the OS X Server admin app. It won't turn off.
Regarding the Perl processes I really don't know where that is used. The info panel doesn't give me any idea. I think it means that one of the sites (I have about 20) is using perl, but I don't know which one.

So, some questions:
- Is it safe to upgrade to OS X El Capitan Server? Should I?
- How can I kill all Perl processes at one time? (I have googled this but couldn't find any working tips)
- Any idea of what's going on?

As you may tell I'm not very skilled with Apache, but I still think it's funny and educating to do this.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqgFc.png)
[Perl processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcscI.png)

Comment: "How can I kill all Perl processes at one time?" `killall perl` (not sure if this is available on OS X, though)

Comment: Thanks, I can't get it to work though: bash-3.2# killall perl
No matching processes were found  
bash-3.2# killall perl*  
No matching processes were found  
bash-3.2# killall perl5.10.0   
No matching processes were found
bash-3.2# killall "perl5.10.0"
No matching processes were found
bash-3.2# 
...?

Answer (score 0):

How can you kill all Perl processes at one time?  `killall` is available on OS X.  Try

```
killall -9 perl
```

HTH

btw - my apologies to ThisSuitIsBlackNot -- I see he referred to this in his comments.

Comment: Did not work. No errors, but all perl processes is still alive. Thanks anyway.